# Receive User Input and Test Whether It is a Float or Not

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that will receive input from a list and justify whether it is a float value or not, and if it is, continue with the program, and if it is not, ask the user to enter the answer a second time. The new value should go into the list at the same index as the previous, incorrect value.

For example, if somebody inputted into my code the value 'seventy-two' instead of 72, I want the inputHandler function to receive this incorrect value, tell the user that it is invalid, and ask the user to answer the same question again.

I want my function to use try-except-else statements. Here is my code:

```
QUIZ_GRADES = int(input("How many quiz grades? "))

PROGRAM_GRADES = int(input("How many program grades? "))

TESTS = int(input("How many tests? "))

def main():

    globalConstantList = [QUIZ_GRADES, PROGRAM_GRADES, TESTS]

    scoreList = [] 

    returnedScoreList = getGrades(globalConstantList,scoreList)

    returnedScoreValue = inputHandler(returnedScoreList)

    returnedScoreValue2 = inputHandler(returnedScoreList)

    returnedScoreListSum, returnedScoreListLength = totalList(returnedScoreList)

    returnedScoreListAverage = calcAverage(returnedScoreListSum,
                                       returnedScoreListLength)

    returnedLetterGrade = determineGrade(returnedScoreListAverage)

    userOutput(returnedScoreListAverage,returnedLetterGrade)

def getGrades(globalConstantList,scoreList):

    for eachScore in globalConstantList:

    #totalScoreList = 0.0

    index = 0

    for index in range(QUIZ_GRADES):

        print("What is the score for", index + 1)

        scoreList.append(float(input()))

        index += 1

    for index in range(PROGRAM_GRADES):

        print("What is the score for", index + 1)

        scoreList.append(float(input()))

        index += 1

    for index in range(TESTS):

        print("What is the score for", index + 1)

        scoreList.append(float(input()))

        index += 1

    return scoreList

def inputHandler(scoreList):

    index = 0

    try:

        print("What is the score for", index + 1)

        scoreList.append(float(input()))

        return scoreList

    except ValueError:

        print("Your value is not correct. Try again.")

        print("What is the score for", index + 1)

        scoreList.append(float(input()))

        return scoreList


def totalList(newScoreList):

    returnedScoreListLength = len(newScoreList)

    returnedScoreListSum = sum(newScoreList)

    return returnedScoreListSum, returnedScoreListLength

def calcAverage(newScoreListSum, newScoreListLength):

    returnedScoreListAverage = newScoreListSum / newScoreListLength

    return returnedScoreListAverage

def determineGrade(newScoreListAverage):

    if newScoreListAverage >= 90:

       return 'A'

    elif newScoreListAverage >= 80:

       return 'B'

    elif newScoreListAverage >= 70:

       return 'C'

    elif newScoreListAverage >= 60:

       return 'D'

    else:

      return 'F'

def userOutput(newScoreListAverage, newLetterGrade):

    print("Your overall grade is",format(newScoreListAverage,'.2f'))

    print("Your letter grade is",newLetterGrade)

    print()
main()
```

Comment: "If some things don't look correctly formatted do not worry about it." but it shows a lack of interest on your part in your question. You haven't stated what is actually wrong with your code; if your syntax was represented correctly, we might be able to guess what isn't working. What is your question?

Comment: in addition to @roganjosh: Python is both case- and indentation-sensitive (if one may say so). Due to this, the indentation is somehow part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to check an user's input and convert it to a `float`. If successful, you want to proceed, if not, you want to ask again.

Assuming this is the case, you might want to write a function which asks for user input, tries to convert input to float, and returns it if successful.

```
def input_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            inp = float(input(prompt))
            return inp
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Try again.')

f = input_float('Enter a float')
print(f)
```

You can then use this snippet as a starting point for further handling of `f` (which is a float) the user provided.

Comment: Unnecessary and incorrect recursion.  Don't call `ask_input()` in `ask_input()`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: If so, what would be correct (since I am working on similar issues currently)?

Comment: A simple loop works...I'll edit your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: That would be great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You can check your number float or int or string using if elif statement then do your work in side the body of your code

```
num =  input("Enter a number ") 
if type(num ) == int : print "This number is an int" 
elif type(num ) == float : print "This number is a float"
```

here you can use function to call this code again and again and place this code in that function and also use try  bock to catch exception .

Comment: this will always return `str`

Comment: then you can cast str into int/float simple and handle the exception

Comment: Side note: use `isinstance(var, type1)` instead of `type(var) == type1`